# WETH burn missing in Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, wrapped-tokens, burn

I'm looking at this transaction in Etherscan(https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdff9b85093c6af369d197815c42930e23b0dfdcd37f8c3e614ca3483cf120af9) and supposedly the address DSProxy #213,717(0xbd2B85Fc052557c58C102254E11D012cfb4A6f45) receives 15.448139753630451409, however, in other explorer there should be a burn event as well(https://ethplorer.io/tx/0xdff9b85093c6af369d197815c42930e23b0dfdcd37f8c3e614ca3483cf120af9#pageTab=transfers&opIdx=20).

Why doesn't this information show in Etherscan?

Comment: Hey, what do you mean burn, for the weth? It shows the unwrap, under withdraw in logs. It also shows as an internal call. When withdraw is called on the weth token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn is something you will see when leaving a liquidity pool.
The weth is unwrapped via calling `withdraw()` on the weth token contract, then transferred with an internal call.

This can be seen both as an internal transfer and as a log:

[image]
[image]

As well as below the interacted with contract:
[image]